# Getting values from an enum

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have some code that sets up a dictionary with some defualt values for an enum:

```
foreach (string status in Enum.GetNames(typeof(TargetStatusType)))
{
    dict.Add((TargetStatusType)Enum.Parse(typeof(TargetStatusType), status), 0);
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this, as it seems a bit messy.

I was hoping I could just do

```
foreach(TargetStatusType status in ?) ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Enum.GetValues()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx):

```
foreach (TargetStatusType type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TargetStatusType)))
```

Note that although `GetValues()` is only declared to return `Array`, the `foreach` loop performs the cast for you automatically. Alternatively you could cast the result to `TargetStatusType[]` if you wanted to use it in a different loop where casting each value would be inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there's no need to use a dictionary here (or to create any sort of new collection for that matter). Also, getting the names of the enum values and then parsing them is a awfully convoluted method when you can just call `GetValues`.

The following should do the job:

```
foreach(var status in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TargetStatusType))
    .Cast<TargetStatusType>())
{
    // ...
}
```

The call to the `Cast` extension method means that your `status` variable is strongly-typed (of type `TargetStatusType`) rather than simply of type `object`.

Answer (score 1):

if this is the initialization of the dictionary (no prior values added) you could also use linq
dict = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TargetStatusType)).ToDictinary(en => en,x => 0)

but I can't help wonder why you would add them to a dictionary. you might have very good reasons :) Im wondering because the value is the same. If it's for a lookup an array index with the int value of the enum will be a lot faster than the dictionary. if you don't care bout the value and only wanna enforce adding the key once, you could use a Hashset<> instead